# Implementing heterogeneous cache and related questions

Tags: c++, caching, memory, c++14, void

I've been asked to design a **heterogeneous Cache class**, meaning that the *key* is a string and the *value* **could be of any type**.
I need to implement 2 methods(among other): `Insert` and `Delete`.

Now, because the value could be of any type, I was thinking of casting it to `void*` (`Insert`), but then, how could I delete a `void*` memory (`Delete`)?

This is how my Insert function looks like:

```
template<typename T>
void CacheSubs::Insert(string const& key, T* obj)
{
    void* copy = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new T{*obj});
    m_map.insert(std::make_pair(key, CacheItem{copy}));
}
```

CacheItem:

```
class CacheItem {
    unsigned int m_access_times{0};
    void* m_data;
    
public:
    CacheItem(void* data);
};
```

Delete should pull CacheItem for a given *key* and call its destructor to free m_data memory

**So I guess my questions are:**

1. Is there a way to cast from `T*` to a `void*` and back? not in the scope.
2. Any other workaround? without having to cast from `void*` to the original type? counting bytes somehow?
3. If none of the above sounds right, how would you design such a class? any lead will help.

Comment: [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) is often a better choice than a void pointer these days. (`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>` would be a good starting point.)

Comment: Sorry, just added to the post, I need a C++ 14 solution if there's one :'-(

Comment: Added a language tag. Don't insert C++14 into the title.

Comment: Are you allowed to use open source libraries such as [Boost](https://www.boost.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) ? You could at least study their source code for inspiration. Have you read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)  and looked into some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website? Provide some [mre] in your question please.

Comment: @Evg 
Maybe at least C++? Because the solution and all the questions are language specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 
Yes I'm allowed, I understand C++ pretty well but I guess I failed to solve this particular problem. 
I'll add some code snippets maybe it could help, but the design is totally up to me so it basically sums up to the questions I asked(1 and 2) which are general questions.

Comment: @katkato, it is a [general recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) not to add language tags into the title at all.

Comment: Basically, you'd need to either reimplement `std::any`, or find a library that does already - e.g. [`boost::any`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/any.html)